# How can I import a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, import

How can I import a generic class?

For example, I try to import the ArrayList class.

I have tried

```
import java.util.ArrayList<>;
```

but the compiler gives me one message, expecting a ';' after the 't'. If I delete the '<>' then I get many errors at compile time.

Comment: "If I delete the '<>' then I get many errors at compile time." - what other errors? Because deleting the `<>` is the correct thing to do. Most likely, you have a program completely full of errors, but putting in this one error hides the rest of them.

Comment: What errors you will get on delete of <>??

Comment: The other errors probably disappeared because this one was so catastrophic it stopped compilation altogether.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: Thanks all. When I compiled without the '<>' I got many errors, all related to the ArrayList object that I had created. When I compiled with '<>' I just got the one error about the '<>'.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This much is enough.